# Play overlapping sound in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm using AVAudioPlayer to play a little shot sound when a user clicks a button. The sounds lasts about 3 seconds and I want that, if a user hit a button multiple times, the shot should sound multiple times. If the user clicks twice in 2 seconds, then the second sound should overlap the first shot.

My problem is that the shot only sounds every 3 seconds (if the user clicks rapidly) instead of every hit of the button.

Inside ViewDidLoad

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"shot" ofType:@"caf"];
urlShotCaf = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlShotCaf error:nil] ;
[player prepareToPlay];
```

And when a person clicks the shot button

```
- (IBAction)tap:(id)sender {
    clicks++;
    [player play];
}
```

Can I do this with AVAudioPlayer? Should I use another framework?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in reference [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html):

> Play multiple sounds simultaneously, one sound per audio player, with precise synchronization

I guess you need a `AVAudioPlayer` for every sound you want to play simultaneously. Otherwise you could use any simple library like [CocosDenshion](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/cocosdenshion%3afaq) that is really simple, easy to embed and powerful (it resides on OpenAL).

Just do

```
[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"yoursound.wav"];
```

and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. It works for me.

```
- (IBAction) tap:(id)sender {
    if ([player isPlaying]) {
        [player stop];
        [player setCurrentTime:0.0];
    }
    [player play];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If high level frameworks fail, then you can dip down to AUSampler - an AudioUnit sample player (typically used for playback of sampled instruments, drum sounds, and so on). This should have very fast response times and support multiple active notes. Configure the sample's playback as one-shot. When the button is pressed, simulate a note on event. You could also map different samples (audio recordings) to different notes and velocity ranges.